Custom Tkinter checkbox loop
I have an unknown number of checkboxes (it is unknown because it depends on data files that change over time). However, as I saw on the web, you need a different variable for each checkbox to get True or False from them. I need to add True and False to a list so I can check them after the user fills out the form.
How do I do that?
this is my checkbox maker:
def Cmaker(defult,tab,filepath,com):
        tv.add(tab)
        global Check
        f=cc.open(filepath , "r", "utf-8")
        A=f.readlines()
        count=len(A)
        
        Xcounter=1
        Ycounter=0
        
        for i in range (count):
            temp=A[i]
            temp=temp.replace("\r\n","")
            check_size_A = tk.StringVar(value=defult)

            check_A=cs.CTkCheckBox(tv.tab(tab) , text=temp ,command=checkboxer, variable=check_size_A, onvalue="on" , offvalue="off")
            check_A.place(relx=(1-((120/1200)*Xcounter)) , rely=0.1+Ycounter)
            Check.append(check_size_A.get())
            if i>0 and i%10==9:
                Ycounter=Ycounter+0.1
                Xcounter=1

                
            else:
                Xcounter=Xcounter+1
        Bmaker (tab,"send",com,100,10,0.5,0.2+Ycounter)
        tv.set(tab)

that Check[] list data is unusable because it stores default values


If you call .get() on your Vars immediately after creating them, then of course you're only going to get the default values!  You need to append the Vars themselves to your list, and then call .get() on them at a point in time when the user has indicated that they've finished changing them.

Thanks a lot. It worked. And if you don't mind, I have another Q. What type of data is stored in my list when I add that var. they are like this <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x000002465F313740>
